# How to use Cookies to prevent login credential sharing in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, authentication, cookies

First of all, I'd like to preface this post by stating that I know this is a terrible user experience...

I have a client who would like to prevent site visitors from sharing login credentials.

Because this is a corporate marketing site, social login is not an option.

The client claims that there is a site where upon registration, a cookie is dropped onto the user's device and the user is also given a unique password that will only work on that specific device.

Does anyone know how to make this work using Wordpress? (I'd like to avoid using third party plugins)

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like the use of Single Sign On (SSO) or 2 factor Authenticaton (2FA) will be needed. The SSO Wikipidea page references a cookie based solution for TCP/IP networks https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_sign-on so perhaps that's how this came up from your client.

Once you identify what your options are with that, based on what your client is using for authentication, then set up may be a bit easier. I think a plugin would save you a lot of time, since this is a pretty elaborate task. This one may do the trick https://wordpress.org/plugins/miniorange-saml-20-single-sign-on/

Regardless it's pretty challenging to prevent the sharing of credentials. SSO may be a deterrent if that gives access to something else that user doesn't want to share. 2FA doesn't prevent a user from sharing the pin thats generated too. Perhaps the only real way is to require an IP match on a device with bio-metric authenticaton.